# How to View dictionary variable value in Sharepoint Designer Workflow. And Loop its value

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-rest-api, dictionary

I am making a REST call in Sharepoint Designer Workflow and value of REST response is storing in dictionary object.But I don't how to view my dictionary object. When I am trying to Log dictionary object in Workflow History list to view its Value at that time workflow goes into Suspended Mode

[image]

Comment: Due to large size of dictionary object . I was not able to log Workflow History.So I sent JSON response in Email body to view it.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to count the items in your dictionary and then iterate through each item to retrieve data.

Refer this link for complete information [Iterate through dictionary](https://plumsail.com/blog/2014/08/how-to-work-with-dictionaries-in-sharepoint-2013-and-office-365-workflow/#IterateThroughDictionary)

Comment: thanks @Monica.. with your solution I am able to Iterate dictionary value but my actual issue was view dictionary value